# How to prove that the phase curve for the effective potential $V_{\rm eff}(r)$ in the Kepler problem have inflection points?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Just as in the plot for effective potential $V_{\rm eff}(r)$, we get inflection point at $r = 3P/2$, $P$ being the conic parameter and given by $c^2/µ$, how can we find the inflection points on its corresponding phase curve (phase space portrait)? I know the the curves would be different for different values of $h$. But even if it could be proved for $h=0$, would do.

Edit: I am adding reference to my problem.

$\ddot{\vec r} = \frac{- µ \vec e_r} {r^2}$ where µ is the gravitational parameter.

We define c as a constant, such that
$\vec c = \vec r$ x $\vec v$

It is from this constant, we know that if $\vec c \neq 0$, then $\vec r \bot {\vec c} \bot {\vec v}$ i.e. the motion is in same plane and if $\vec c = 0$, then motion is rectilinear.

For Kepler Problem, the effective Potential $V_{\rm eff}(r)$ can be written as,

$V_{\rm eff}(r) = \frac{- µ}{r} + \frac {1}{2} \frac {c^2}{r^2}$

From this, it is easy to obtain a curve of $V_{\rm eff}(r)$ vs r and its inflection point at r = 3P/2 as mentioned above.

Also,

$h = \frac{1}{2} \dot r^2 + V_{\rm eff}(r)$

As for the phase curve,

A phase curve or [phase space portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait) is a graphical representation of a system of differential equations, which shows the evolution of the system over time. In this case, it would be a plot between $\vec r$ and $\vec {\dot r}$. I just want to know, what should be my approach in finding the inflection point of this phase curve. For simplicity, it would be okay to stick for a case h = 0.

[image: Phase space portrait of Veff vs r]

Comment: This is unclear. What is $c$? What is $\mu$? What is $h$?

Comment: I am very familiar with the effective potential, but I have no idea what its “phase curve” or “phase space portrait” means. Please either explain or provide a standard reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you interested in the inflection points in the first place? Don’t you mean critical points ($V’(r)=0$)? These are more visible in a phase portrait.

Comment: Yes @Ipz, but just as V'(r) = 0 will give me the critical points and V''(r) = 0 will give me the inflection point in the plot of Veff vs r, I want the similar thing in the phase portrait. Reason - Want to get some insight on how concavity changes. Sorry if doesn't make sense.